# как написать вычислительный цикл на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Задача такова: при каждом повторении цикла, происходит вычисление, 1000 - 7, 993-7, 986 - 7 и так должно продолжатся пока цикл не дойдёт до нуля. Возможно моя задачка кому то покажется странной, но в целях изучения концепции циклов, хотелось бы разобраться не в банальных примерах, а в действительно длинном и сложном цикле. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: В чем ваша проблема при написании данного цикла?

Comment: В этом цикле нет ничего длинного и ничего сложного - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: здесь за вас никто дединсайдовские скрипты писать не будет. пытайтесь сами не быть гулем.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ:

```
var i = 1000; // стартовое значение
while(i > 0) { // будет работать пока i больше 0
  console.log(i); // выводим значение в консоль
  i -= 7; // отнимаем 7 от i
}
```

*Советую изучать уроки по JavaScript, что бы не было таких вопросов в дальнейшем.*

Comment: Премного вам благодарен! Спасибо

Comment: Я бы не отказался от выбора моего ответа - как верного.